# Android/Java - DateTime attribute for MySQL Database

Tags: java, android, mysql, datetime

I have seen the question several times but many are outdated and many of the answers are now deprecated.

I am currently coding an app when a user sends a message to a support team, and in the database the message has a "datetime" CREATED_AT field.

I have read the documentation and now I have this in my message class (the message itself will be included in a "ticket" object) :

```
private final int ID_SPM;
   private final Date SPM_CREATED_AT;
   private String spmContent;
```

This is the constructor :

```
public SupportMessage(int ID_SPM, Date SPM_CREATED_AT, String spmContent) {
        this.ID_SPM = ID_SPM;
        this.SPM_CREATED_AT = SPM_CREATED_AT;
        this.setSpmContent(spmContent);
    }
```

So here I invoke the constructor. I put a fake ID since it will be autoincremented in the db but I had to put one default since it is final :

```
SupportMessage spm = new SupportMessage(0, Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), inputMsg.getText().toString());
```

The API to access the database is not created yet so I can't try if it works. I certainly won't be able to try it before my internship ends (I use hardcoded data for testing in a fake "callAPI" class which will be replaced by the proper methods)

Yet I want to make a good and clean job so...

Here is what the console log poutputs :

```
I/SUPMSG: SupportMessage{ID_SPM=0, SPM_CREATED_AT=Wed Nov 06 12:04:25 GMT+01:00 2019, spmContent='hhh'}
```

This does not look like a MySQL datetime... Will this be okay since it is an object and the Database will autoformat it or do I have to convert it as an SQL formatted string? 
How do I do that in a not deprecated way?

I know there is android documentation and I read it but I'm new into it and a bit lost between all the different date things some of which are deprecated (the ones I learned how to use :'() Moreover I got an introduction to PHP just before starting my internship and it completely confused me with the date stuff I knew from java x@

Again, please excuse me if my English is bad, I'm a french student and try to do my best to be clear.

Comment: MySQL will hold a date as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` You can use PHP to format that any way you want before passing it back to the Android or better still let the Andriod code do what it wants with it

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But is my code OK to pass the value to the Database ? Is it ok for MySQL to get this from android code ? What do you mean by "what it wants with it" ? 
For display use I can convert from mysql to string, that I know to do. But I don't know if my code will send a proper datetime to mysql ?

Comment: Simple answer: Send it to the PHP API in the above format and not to much can go wrong

Comment: Okay, so this leads to the second part of my question, how do I do that in a not deprecated way ?

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Oh thank you i''ll give it a look !